# Parameter Tampering in Oracle

Tags: oracle, security, plsql, parameters

I scanned my Oracle package using the tool Checkmarx for security vulnerabilities. Checkmarx generated a report saying that my code has a vulnerability type Parameter Tampering. I will be running the code directly in the database itself without any front end application. In such a case will Parameter Tampering be an issue. If yes, then how do I add validations in my package itself to prevent Parameter Tampering?

I cannot put my actual code here but it is something like this:

```
PROCEDURE TEST1(START_DATE IN DATE) IS 
BEGIN 
    END_DATE := TO_DATE(TRUNC(LAST_DAY(START_DATE)), 'DD-MON-RRRR');
```

Comment: Sorry, cannot answer your question on the basis of the information you have supplied.

Comment: Never call TO_DATE with a date.

Answer (score 4):

```
END_DATE := TO_DATE(TRUNC(LAST_DAY(START_DATE)), 'DD-MON-RRRR');
```

The expression contains implicit date conversion.  The `TO_DATE` function expects a string; the date returned by `TRUNC` is implicitly converted
into a string, which is then explicitly converted back to a date.  The `TO_DATE` is redundant and can be removed.

There are ways to mess with the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter to subvert date conversion, but I don't see a security issue in this case.

However the tool is wise to warn you about the date handling here.  The `TO_DATE` function is always suspect and is improperly used 99% of the time.

Comment: I removed the To_Date(), but it still showed the same issue. Moreover when I scanned my code which had compilation errors, the result contained 0 issues. It was the same code with one extra comma.

Answer (score 1):

Parameter tampering exploits weaknesses in web front-end applications to change the values of parameters for nefarious purposes.  With stored procedures the biggest worry is SQL injection, where an attacker tricks the database into running arbitrary code

If your stored procedure does not take input from a web front-end then parameter tampering is not really a threat.  However, if the business logic is sensitive in some fashion, and especially if your code include dynamic SQL operations, then it is worthwhile building some defences.

Use [design-by-contract principles](http://www.nocoug.org/download/2005-08/AEMS_ppt.pdf) to verify the values and format of input parameters, and raise exceptions for invalid values.  For instance, if a string is supposed to contain a date, ensure that it does contain a string which can be cast to a date.

Generally speaking strong data types are better than using strings to pass everything.   (In my opinion `RR` is a bug: it's 2015 already, and all applications should be using four-digit years.)

Oracle has a built-in package called DBMS_ASSERT.  Its functionality allows us to validate the contents of string parameters, to prevent SQL injection. [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_assert.htm#ARPLS231).